# What is the production-readiness of sails.js and meteor.js, and how to they compare to Django?

Tags: django, node.js, meteor, sails.js

I am thinking of using either one of them in building our startup which is like a job portal with validation,verification and includes special features for freelancing and all.

Is meteor or sails good for using as a backend or should we go with more robust backend like Django? Will using javascript on our backend provide the ability to scale in the future moreso than Django/python?

I would really like some opinions in this matter to get to a decision.

Answer (score 8):

sails.js and meteor are both great options for production.

Both frameworks have good real-time (socket.io) support, large/active communities, support a stateless backend design which make horizontal scalability possible, and are great for getting a web application spun up quickly.

### sails.js - http://sailsjs.org

- broad database support through the Waterline ORM (there are over a dozen supported databases)
- concepts should more familiar to most node.js developers (it's built on express)
- modeled after rails, grails, and django, so the paradigm is more familiar to developers with experience in those tools
- extensible through npm package manager via express middleware and custom modules

### meteor - https://www.meteor.com

- better integration between the backend and frontend
- project is VC-backed with a firmer corporate backing
- extensible using custom package manager and extension system
- built-in deployment system and hosting on meteor.com

> Will using javascript on our backend provide the ability to scale in the future moreso than Django/python?

Probably. As with anything, you just have to do it right.

My overall opinion is that meteor is sort of cult-ish and monolithic, and that once you've chosen it, you're locked in. sails.js is built on express, so it's easy to split out functionality and integrate with other tools.

My disclaimer is that I work for Balderdash (the company that invented sails.js); but on that note, I can also tell you that millions of users are served by sails.js applications. We find that it's quite good, and our business is thriving because of the power of sails.js. I know folks who have used meteor with success as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Travis.I am also more inclined to use sails than metoer but I found more articles about metoer than on sails since it is much recent than metoer.We might go with it. :D

Comment: sails and meteor have both been around for over two years now. Meteor is backed by silicon valley money, so they've been sponsoring articles and offering prizes to people who star their github repo. In my opinion, meteor *appears* more popular than it actually *is*.

Comment: I don't want to sound overly cynical about meteor, again, I think it's a great tool, I've just found sails to suit my needs better. I started out as a sails.js contributor about a year ago, having chosen it over meteor :) If you'd like to chat more and get a better perspective, the sails.js gitter room is a great place to hang out: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a primarily opinion-based question, so you're going to receive answers from the very same "type".

But I can tell you one thing: Meteor is robust enough for production use, specially now that they hit the 1.1 release (https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/03/31/meteor-11-microsoft-windows-mongodb-30).

Meteor is perfectly suited for startups, since it brings everything you need (and more) into a single "pack".

Check this: http://meteorpedia.com/read/Why_Meteor

So yah, that's my answer going for the Meteor side.. (not very technical, I know).