# Difference between MEAN.io and Sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, mean-stack, mean.io

What is the difference between these two? Are they mutually exclusive, or can you run sails.js and mean.io at the same time? If they are mutually exclusive, pros and cons of using one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MEAN (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) stack is just that: a pre-built stack consisting of those components. sails is also built on node.js and express, but it supports other frontend libraries beyond angular, and other databases beyond just mongo.

I think you wouldn't want to try to use them both; sails.js does everything mean.io does, but you get the additional flexibility of support for other UI tools and databases. sails.js supports over a dozen databases, including Mongo.

Some additional info on sails is in a similar StackOverflow question that I answered, here: [What is the production-readiness of sails.js and meteor.js, and how to they compare to Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385416/what-is-the-production-readiness-of-sails-js-and-meteor-js-and-how-to-they-comp/29401667#29401667)